# margin-top in parent, negative top in child, how to get rid of the leftover height below

Tags: html, css

I have a design that requires white background, but the top 100px needs to be without background. So what I did, I used margin-top to push down div that has the white background and put another div inside of this div and pulled it up using negative of what I used to push the first one down. It works fine. But because of this, I have 100px of unused space below and I need to get rid of it. How can I achieve it?

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="margin-top" style="margin-top: 100px;">
   <div id="negative-top" style="position: relative; top: -100px;">
      content
   </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: I got it working! 

#container has to have overflow: hidden; and in margin-top: i used relative and top: 100px;

Answer (score 2):

Try this method, it will work for you.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="margin-top" style="margin-top: 100px;">
<div id="negative-top" style="margin-top: -100px; padding-top: 100px">
content
</div>
</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gradient instead of background-color on your body and get rid of negative margin.

```css
background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 20px, #000000 20px, #000000 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 20px,#000000 20px,#000000 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 20px,#000000 20px,#000000 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```